# Programmatically register a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'd like to know what is the best practice/way of programmatically register a broadcast receiver. I want to register specific receivers according to user choice.

As the registration is done through the manifest file, I'm wondering if there's a proper way to achieve this in code.

Comment: [CoderzPassion Broadcast Reciever](http://www.coderzpassion.com/implement-broadcastreceiver-android) best detailed tutorial ever

Comment: **Please refer this Link** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app/44881551#44881551

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It sounds like you want to control whether  components published in your manifest are active, not dynamically register a receiver (via Context.registerReceiver()) while running.

If so, you can use PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting() to control whether these components are active:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setComponentEnabledSetting(android.content.ComponentName, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setComponentEnabledSetting%28android.content.ComponentName,%20int,%20int%29)

Note if you are only interested in receiving a broadcast while you are running, it is better to use registerReceiver().  A receiver component is primarily useful for when you need to make sure your app is launched every time the broadcast is sent.

Comment: Clever ! You got me straight. Thank you very much

Comment: Nice one - had no idea you could do this :)

Comment: it is similar 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140894/can-i-register-the-widget-from-java-code-instead-of-android-manifest

Comment: @hackbod How can add meta-data tag in custom receiver ? Have you any idea !! I need to add meta-data  tag which one we use in androidmanifest.xml.

Comment: Best tutorial till date http://coderzpassion.com/implement-broadcastreceiver-android/ and in simple language

Answer (score 284):

In your `onCreate` method you can register a receiver like this:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

  // your oncreate code should be

  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
  filter.addAction("SOME_ACTION");
  filter.addAction("SOME_OTHER_ACTION");

  receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      //do something based on the intent's action
    }
  };
     registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}
```

Remember to run this in the `onDestroy` method:

```
 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  if (receiver != null) {
   unregisterReceiver(receiver);
   receiver = null;
  }
  super.onDestroy();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. To send the broadcast I used the code Intent i = new Intent("SOME_ACTION"); sendBroadcast(i);

Comment: why not in on resume and on start?

Comment: What would happen if I do not unregister the broadcast receiver ?
Would it leave the broadcast receiver registered, even after reboot ?

Comment: It's not guaranteed that `onDestroy()` will be called, thus creating a potential memory leak. It's better to register/unregister in `onStart()`/`onStop()`.

Comment: Does this mean I don't have to create a broadcast receiver class? I could just put all my onReceive() code here and it'd work?

Comment: At this level , everything is working fine, but if like to include the " Pending intent " and alarm manager , nothing received or triggered , below is the added code

Comment: :PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),100,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

Comment: AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);

Answer (score 72):

One important point that people forget to mention is the life time of the `Broadcast Receiver`. The difference of programmatically registering it from  registering in **AndroidManifest.xml** is that. In the manifest file, it doesn't depend on application life time. While when programmatically registering it it does depend on the application life time. This means that if you register in **AndroidManifest.xml**, you can catch the broadcasted intents even when your application is not running.

**Edit:** The mentioned note is no longer true as of Android 3.1, the Android system excludes all receiver from receiving intents by default if the corresponding application has never been started by the user or if the user explicitly stopped the application via the Android menu (in Manage → Application). https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html

This is an additional security feature as the user can be sure that only the applications he started will receive broadcast intents.

So it can be understood as receivers programmatically registered in Application's `onCreate()` would have same effect with ones declared in **AndroidManifest.xml** from Android 3.1 above.

Comment: This is a good note. I am actually looking at a book I am reading about android and wondering why both 2 methods of implementing broadcast has been done. It does seem to me that it is for backward-compatibility. But I am not sure though.

Comment: Well, do you really thing that the edit is true? I mean the last sentence. Android is likely to kill your application at any time, which will result in your programmatically registered receivers to not work anymore, but the manifest registered will still work.

Answer (score 44):

Define a broadcast receiver anywhere in Activity/Fragment like this:

```
mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Log.d(TAG," onRecieve"); //do something with intent
   }
 };
```

Define IntentFilter in `onCreate()`

```
mIntentFilter=new IntentFilter("action_name");
```

Now register the BroadcastReciever in `onResume()` and Unregister it in `onPause()` [because there is no use of broadcast if the activity is paused].

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(mReceiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
            mReceiver = null;
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

For detail tutorial, have a look at [broadcast receiver-two ways to implement](http://sohailaziz05.blogspot.com/2012/05/broadcast-receiver-two-ways-to.html).

Comment: @SohailAziz The link provides a good answer. Could you put the context of the link in your answer, so that if the link goes down, your answer remains relevant?

Comment: in my personal views, broadcast should be registered in onResume and onPause as you suggested but some people say it must be on onCreate and onDestroy, can you explain pros and cons for both?

Comment: @SyedRazaMehdi if broadcast is used to update UI [which is in most cases] you should register it in onResume and unregister in onPause because broadcast will be useless otherwise.

Comment: Thanks.This is best answer.

Comment: @SohailAziz If you are using the broadcast inside an activity, then you can still update the UI if you register it in onCreate() and unregister in onDestory(), since the view isn't destroyed after onPause(), for fragments it can be onViewCreated() and onDestroyView(). But I agree that onPause() and onResume() are the safest places to receive a broadcast meant for UI rendering.

Answer (score 4):

```
package com.example.broadcastreceiver;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   UserDefinedBroadcastReceiver broadCastReceiver = new UserDefinedBroadcastReceiver();

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

   /**
    * This method enables the Broadcast receiver for
    * "android.intent.action.TIME_TICK" intent. This intent get
    * broadcasted every minute.
    *
    * @param view
    */
   public void registerBroadcastReceiver(View view) {

      this.registerReceiver(broadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            "android.intent.action.TIME_TICK"));
      Toast.makeText(this, "Registered broadcast receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
   }

   /**
    * This method disables the Broadcast receiver
    *
    * @param view
    */
   public void unregisterBroadcastReceiver(View view) {

      this.unregisterReceiver(broadCastReceiver);

      Toast.makeText(this, "unregistered broadcst receiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain to OP why this is the best practice?

Comment: They don't explain, "they" always post code, because its much better you know. -sarcasm

Answer (score 3):

## Two choices

> 1) If you want to read Broadcast only when the Activity is visible
>   then,

`registerReceiver(...`) in `onStart()` and `unregisterReceiver(...)` in `onStop()`

> 2) If you want to read Broadcast even if Activity is in Background
>   then,

`registerReceiver(...)` in `onCreate(...)` and `unregisterReceiver(...)` in `onDestroy()`

## Bonus:

> If you are lazy

If you don't want to write boilerplate code for registering and unregistering a BroadcastReceiver again and again in each Activity then,

1. Create an abstract Activity
2. Write boilerplate code in Activity
3. Leave the implementation as abstract methods

**Here is the code snippet:**

> Abstract Activity

```
public abstract class BasicActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
    private IntentFilter filter;
    private static final String TAG = "BasicActivity";

    /**********************************************************************
    *                   Boilerplate code
    **********************************************************************/

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle sis){
        super.onCreate(sis);
        broadcastReceiver = getBroadcastReceiver();
        filter = getFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        register();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        unregister();
    }

    private void register(){
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,filter);
    }

    private void unregister(){
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }

    /**********************************************************************
    *                   Abstract methods
    **********************************************************************/

    public abstract BroadcastReceiver getBroadcastReceiver();

    public abstract IntentFilter getFilter();

}
```

> Using this approach you can write more boilerplate code such as
>   writing common animations, binding to a service, etc.

### See full code:

[HERE](https://github.com/rohitksingh/ReceiverActivity)

Answer (score 2):

According to Listening For and Broadcasting Global Messages, and Setting Alarms in [Common Tasks and How to Do Them in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html):

> If the receiving class is not
>   registered using  in its
>   manifest, you can dynamically
>   instantiate and register a receiver by
>   calling **Context.registerReceiver()**.

Take a look at [registerReceiver  (BroadcastReceiver  receiver, IntentFilter  filter)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29) for more info.

Comment: i tried calling `context.registerReceiver` but its not getting called can you please look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238600/use-registerreceiver-for-non-activity-and-non-service-class

Answer (score 2):

It is best practice to always supply the permission when registering the receiver, otherwise you will receive for any application that sends a matching intent. This can allow malicious apps to broadcast to your receiver.

Answer (score 2):

for **LocalBroadcastManager**

```
   Intent intent = new Intent("any.action.string");
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).
                                sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and register in `onResume`

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(
                    ActivityName.this).registerReceiver(chatCountBroadcastReceiver, filter);
```

and Unregister it `onStop`

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(
                ActivityName.this).unregisterReceiver(chatCountBroadcastReceiver);
```

and recieve it ..

```
mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e("mBroadcastReceiver", "onReceive");
        }
    };
```

where IntentFilter is

```
 new IntentFilter("any.action.string")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create a broadcast receiver**

[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = false)]

```
public class BCReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{

    BCReceiver receiver;

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        //Do something here
    }
}
```

**From your activity add this code:**

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ApplicationContext)
    .registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```