# Can I listen for GPS changes?

Tags: android

I am writing app, that collects location data, based on GPS. And i have next problem:
when i try to get GPS data and GPS is turned off, i show notification that ask for turning on GPS, and it starts(on click of course) intent with "ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS". Question: how can i know that user turned it on? is there some broadcasted actions, or i can set some listener, or something else?

Comment: i need get it as fast as it possible. and yes i know i can start some service that can check this, but it can take a long time while user change settings, and it will cost a lot of battery and system resources. or not?

Comment: Hey i have not worked yet with GPS applications. But this was i able to find something for you : http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/186/make-certain-apps-turn-on-gps-automatically

Comment: @Kartik it possibly uses in application turn on GPS through reflection i guess. that not solution for me(

Comment: Try this one [Broadcast Receiver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805269/programmatically-register-a-broadcast-receiver): i think it will help you

Comment: @Kartik yes but what action i should listen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener 
{

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    GlobalHelper.handler.post(GlobalHelper.update_location);

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    GlobalHelper.system_message(provider + " Ausgeschaltet", 0,false);
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    GlobalHelper.system_message(provider + " Eingeschaltet",0,false);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
    Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

Comment: OMG i forgot that in LocationListener there is such method to fire GPS state, my mistake. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor android system settings, see [Monitor Android system settings values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190779/monitor-android-system-settings-values)