# How to make a background service that monitor wifi state

Tags: android, android-service, android-wifi

I want to make a background service that always runs in background service. When mobile connected with internet via WI-FI it notice me. so please help me.. I am newbie.
Thanks.

here is my code-

```
public class MyService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "My Service Demo";
Context _context;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
```

> //Create object for ConnectivityManager class which returns network
>   related info

```
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

> //If connectivity object is not null

```
        if (connectivity != null) {
```

> ```
>  //Get network info - WIFI internet access
> ```

```
            NetworkInfo info = connectivity.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

            if (info != null) {
```

> //Look for whether device is currently connected to WIFI network

```
                if (info.isConnected()) {
                    Toast.makeText(_context,"wi fi connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

        }
        }
        }
```

}

Comment: Services are _not_ meant to run all the time.

Comment: well first of all, where is your problem? i mean you told us what u want the achieve but not where u cant figure out what to do, im to lazy to read the whole code and figure out the problem myself

Comment: Actually you need a Receiver to do that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362314/wifi-connect-disconnect-listener

Comment: thanks joao2fast4u for your referrence