# How to detect exact time of Network/Internet unavailability..?

Tags: android

Just I want to detect the exact & sharp time of Internet/Network disconnected or connection no longer available.. Suppose my app is connected to some server after some time I lost my connection with server(say @ 02:30:15 PM) quickly at the same time I wana detect that time(02:30:15 PM) or I get alert that for this particular movement I lost my Connectivity..

Even if I have Wi-Fi or data connectivity is available I lost my connection..?

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362314/wifi-connect-disconnect-listener) link,it give a example of Brodacast Receiver for Connect/Disconnct event of wifi connection.

Implement Same BroadcastReceiver in your project and listen for connect and disconnect event, and at same time get system time by `System.currentTimeMillis()` method. Then you have the connect and disconnect time.

Hope this will be helpfull for you.

Comment: Ya this is useful but still I don't want event on WI-FI connect-disconnect rather I want to detect time of connectivity lost even if I connected to WI-FI i.e. detection depend upon weak or poor WI-FI signals

Comment: when connection is lost for either one second then receiver will call and you have time of connectivity lost.