# Difference between registerDefaultNetworkCallback and registerNetworkCallback

Tags: java, android, kotlin, network-programming, android-connectivitymanager

I came across [registerDefaultNetworkCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#registerDefaultNetworkCallback) and [registerNetworkCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#registerNetworkCallback) while updating my Android app for API 28.

Having reviewed the documentation, I cannot find the difference between registering a **network callback** and registering a *default* **network callback**.

When will one use which?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As far as I understood, the difference between `registerDefaultNetworkCallback` and `registerNetworkCallback` it's only based on customisation.
`registerDefaultNetworkCallback` works (surprisingly) as a default network listener, while `registerNetworkCallback` it's more configurable. For example:

```
    val connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

    val builder = NetworkRequest.Builder()
    builder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)

    val networkRequest = builder.build()
    connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, 
    object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback () {
        override fun onAvailable(network: Network?) {
            super.onAvailable(network)
            Log.i("Test", "Network Available")
        }

        override fun onLost(network: Network?) {
            super.onLost(network)
            Log.i("Test", "Connection lost")
        }
    })
```

Here `onAvailable` will be called only if the user connects to a cellular network (by connecting to WiFi it won't log anything). The same does `onLost` when disconnecting from cellular network.

If we do it like this:

```
    connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(object  : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        override fun onAvailable(network: Network?) {
            super.onAvailable(network)
            Log.i("Test", "Default -> Network Available")
        }

        override fun onLost(network: Network?) {
            super.onLost(network)
            Log.i("Test", "Default -> Connection lost")
        }
    })
```

Both functions work as default callbacks when the user is connecting (or disconnecting) to/from a network (it can be either WiFi or cellular).

These are just some very basic examples. Of course `NetworkRequest` can have a lot of configurations by setting its `capability` or `transportType`. You can read more about these in the official documentation of [NetworkRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkRequest.html).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Where does this code go? In `onCreate`?

Comment: Note that `onAvailable` will not happen in the main thread, so any UI updates would need to be in side a `runOnUiThread { /* code */ }` block.

Comment: In my case 'registerNetworkCallback' onAvailable works also for wifi connect and disconnect .

Answer (score 17):

**`registerNetworkCallback()`** was added in API level 21 (Android 5.0, Lollipop). It allows you to listen for changes in networks which satisfy a certain **transport type** (WiFi, cellular, Bluetooth, ...) and **capability** (SMS, `NOT_METERED`, ...).

**`registerDefaultNetworkCallback()`** was added in API level 24 (Android 7.0, Nougat) and uses your callback when any network change occurs, regardless of transport type and capability.

---

Example for **`registerNetworkCallback()`**. At least in my case I do not care about the filters and want my code to run for any network type. This can be achieved with an empty `Builder` object:

```kotlin
/* Automatically start a download once an internet connection is established */
val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
// could filter using .addCapability(int) or .addTransportType(int) on Builder
val networkChangeFilter = NetworkRequest.Builder().build()
cm.registerNetworkCallback(networkChangeFilter, 
    object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) = downloadStuff()
    }
)
```

Above code is equivalent to this code with **`registerDefaultNetworkCallback()`**:

```kotlin
val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
cm.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(
    object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) = downloadStuff()
    }
)
```

The confusingly named `NetworkRequest` is actually just a filter for transport type and capability.

---

**The `Default` version is less code, but has a lower API level and thus supports fewer phones (74% vs 94%).** Since I could not find a backwards-compatible version of this API call in [`ConnectivityManagerCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/net/ConnectivityManagerCompat) I recommend using the first version if API levels 21-23 matter to you.

Answer (score 7):

The most important difference was highlighted by always-learning. My answer will be the same, but I will try to explain it in a different way.

The device can be connected to a few networks simultaneously(WiFI and mobile for example). Android chooses one of the connected networks as the **default** so that **default network** is used for requests.

The difference is `registerNetworkCallback` notifies about **all connected networks**, and `registerDefaultNetworkCallback` notifies about **default netowork**.

*This is why you can't pass filter in `registerDefaultNetworkCallback` - it doesn't make sense to filter one chosen default network, but it does make sense for `registerNetworkCallback` because there are can be many available networks*.

You can find a very good example [on Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/reading-network-state#example) that explains which callbacks do you get in `registerDefaultNetworkCallback` and `registerNetworkCallback`

Answer (score 3):

Most of these answers are more or less correct. That said, what I can add is that *default network* has a particular meaning in Android hence the difference in naming. The default network pertains to whichever network is chosen as the "best" device wide network. This network will be used by *default* for any connectivity requests.

If you are using a phone and only have a Cellular connection available, that will be the default network. As soon as you connect to Wi-Fi however that will become the default network as it is considered the "best" network and all connectivity requests which don't specify anything different will now use it *by default* whether they realize it or not. This is because Wi-Fi is considered better then Cellular as long as Wi-Fi has `NetworkCapability.NET_CAPABILITY_NOT_METERED`. Now if it turns out that the Wi-Fi network is in fact a metered network while cellular isn't, then the default network would switch back to cellular.

Therefore when you use `registerDefaultNetworkCallback()`, what you are really saying is let me know about changes that occur on the network tagged as the "best" network on the device that all apps will use *by default* unless they request something different. This is why you don't need to pass a `NetworkCapability` as part of the registration since the default network is controlled by the framework.

`registerNetworkCallback()` is similar except that it doesn't care about the default network. You give it some `NetworkCapability` and you track on any networks that satisfy those network capabilities regardless of whether they are the default or not.

You can see more by looking at `getDefaultNetwork()` in [ConnectivityService](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java;l=522?q=connectivityservice&sq=).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've understood, and aside of the information provided by @MihaiV , there's another difference between them.

`ConnectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback()` was added in API 24 (or 26, depending if you use it along a `Handler`).

`And ConnectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback()` was added in API 21 (or API 23 if used along a `NetworkRequest`.

Comment: Both signatures of `registerNetworkCallback` require a `NetworkRequest` -- the difference is in the callback type (`NetworkCallback` vs `PendingIntent`)

Answer (score 1):

i found guide document page:
[Android Developers > Docs > Guides > Reading network state](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/reading-network-state).

`registerDefaultNetworkCallback` , `registerNetworkCallback` and `default network` are explained.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which works for both Android versions (24 and above, and below):

```
class NetworkMonitor(
    private val application: Application,
    val onChange: (isConnected: Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    fun register() {
        (application.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager).let { connectivityManager ->
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                registerAPI24AndAbove(connectivityManager)
            } else {
                registerAPI24Below(connectivityManager)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun registerAPI24AndAbove(connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager) {
        connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(buildNetworkCallback())
    }

    private fun registerAPI24Below(connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager) {
        NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
            .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
            .build().let { networkRequest ->
                connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, buildNetworkCallback())
            }
    }

    private fun buildNetworkCallback(): ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback {
        return object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

            override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                this@NetworkMonitor.onChange(true)
            }

            override fun onLost(network: Network) {
                this@NetworkMonitor.onChange(false)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you declare the required permission!

```
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
```

Then in your Application class:

```
class MyApp : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        NetworkMonitor(this) { isConnected ->
            if (isConnected) {
                // Do your thing
            } else {
                // Do your other thing
            }
        }.register()
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a coding solution, but doesn't answer the question: i.e. the difference.