# Update UI from consumer service

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-service-binding

I am building a simple producer-consumer usecase in android with following features:

1. Main Activity has a Fullscreen ImageView
2. Producer service populates a queue with images and time for which each image must be viewed
3. Consumer thread reads these images and sets the imageView for time mentioned.

MainActivity:

> ```
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>     ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
>     Intent consumerServiceIntent = new Intent(this, PlaylistConsumer.class);
>     startService(consumerServiceIntent);
> ```

How do I update imageView from PlaylistConsumer class ?

Comment: read about `bound [local] service` pattern

Comment: How do I update the imageView component from bindservice ?

Comment: Spent lot of time on this. I need a way to update UI components from service. Still not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: if you spent lot of time so what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to [send broadcast from your service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211824/send-broadcast-from-service-to-activity)

```
// somewhere in PlaylistConsumer, when it needs to update
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(I_HAVE_CONSUMED_PLAYLIST); // I_HAVE_CONSUMED_PLAYLIST is public static final String
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

then, in the activity, [create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211824/send-broadcast-from-service-to-activity) and [register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805269/programmatically-register-a-broadcast-receiver) Broadcast receiver

```
//create
mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
     //update myImageView here
   }
 };
//register
@Override
protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(PlaylistConsumer.I_HAVE_CONSUMED_PLAYLIST));
}
// unregister when paused
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(mReceiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        mReceiver = null;
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

I also recommend to use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to register and send broadcasts.