# How do i prevent my broadcast receiver from getting killed?

Tags: android

i have a broadcast receiver which calls an asynctask onReceive. it works fine, however, whenever i kill all apps from the task manager, my broadcast receiver also gets killed.

```
    package com.android.systemmanager;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class InternetSuckerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String url = "https://s.yimg.com/zz/combo?pj/sh/201512112045/img/help.icon-sprite.png";
        new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
    }
```

Comment: Obvious it will be !

Comment: im sure there will be a solution

Comment: don't unregister the broadcast receiver only register it

Comment: Why dont you start a service

Comment: Please look at CommonsWare answer. He has added a good content in that 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10398237/3210285

Comment: use a STICKY service whose job will be to always keep your receiver alive

Comment: @jois can i fire the method in my service from an activity? im doing the same. firing onreceive of my broadcastreceiver from my activity

Comment: Yes you can start service from your Actvity