# Android:unable to register BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I am trying to register a receiver using java and not the manifest, as I don't need this receiver work when my app is close.

If I use the manifest my receiver work well:

```
 <receiver android:name=".services.PlayerService$RemoteControlReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

If I register it in my activity without the manifest, this don't work at all:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    {
        filter.addAction("android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON");
    }

    registerReceiver(RemoteControlReceiver, filter);
```

I don't need to use the manifest, as I want to control the headset button only when my app is open.

Comment: is your class really has this name with $ symbol. PlayerService$RemoteControlReceiver

Comment: Check this SO thread it will help you [Programmatically register a broadcast receiver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805269/programmatically-register-a-broadcast-receiver) Share with me if still you get any trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` instead of `android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON` as;

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);    
filter.setPriority(10000);    
registerReceiver(RemoteControlReceiver, filter);
```