# BroadcastReceiver crashes Android application when connection state changes

Tags: android, crash, broadcastreceiver

I have the following code:

```
    private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    /*
    boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
    String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
    boolean isFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);

    NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
    NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);
    */
    // do application-specific task(s) based on the current network state, such 
    // as enabling queuing of HTTP requests when currentNetworkInfo is connected etc.
//  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //      if(!check3G()||!checkWifi())
        updateUI();
    }
    };
       /*
        * method to be invoked to register the receiver
        */
       private void registerReceivers() {    
           registerReceiver(mConnReceiver, 
               new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
       }
```

And I register the receiver in the oncreate method like so:

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
    registerReceivers();
    /* Code omitted*/
    }
```

And in ondestroy as

```
    public void onDestroy(){
     unregisterReceiver(mConnReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();      
}
```

Now whenever the connection state changes, I want to call updateUI();

But when it does change, the function is called, but the application crashes. I am unsure what I am doing wrong and any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Edit:

LogCat Log:

```
09-05 04:04:56.968: I/ActivityManager(246): Start proc edu.ucla.pam for activity edu.ucla.pam/.LoginScreenActivity: pid=7158 uid=10008 gids={3003, 3002, 3001, 1015, 1028}
09-05 04:04:57.757: I/ActivityManager(246): Displayed edu.ucla.pam/.LoginScreenActivity: +856ms
09-05 04:05:23.347: I/ActivityManager(246): START {cmp=edu.ucla.pam/.MenuMainActivity (has extras) u=0} from pid 7158
09-05 04:05:23.574: I/ActivityManager(246): Displayed edu.ucla.pam/.MenuMainActivity: +173ms
09-05 04:05:37.386: E/AndroidRuntime(7158): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver edu.ucla.pam.receiver.ConnectivityReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.ucla.pam.receiver.ConnectivityReceiver
09-05 04:05:37.386: E/AndroidRuntime(7158): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.ucla.pam.receiver.ConnectivityReceiver
09-05 04:05:37.398: W/ActivityManager(246):   Force finishing activity edu.ucla.pam/.MenuMainActivity
09-05 04:05:37.925: W/ActivityManager(246): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{4225a750 edu.ucla.pam/.MenuMainActivity}
09-05 04:05:39.296: I/ActivityManager(246): Process edu.ucla.pam (pid 7158) has died.
09-05 04:05:39.296: I/WindowState(246): WIN DEATH: Window{4221fec0 edu.ucla.pam/edu.ucla.pam.LoginScreenActivity paused=false}
09-05 04:05:39.300: I/WindowState(246): WIN DEATH: Window{4250fe58 edu.ucla.pam/edu.ucla.pam.MenuMainActivity paused=false}
09-05 04:05:39.304: W/ActivityManager(246): Force removing ActivityRecord{42153568 edu.ucla.pam/.LoginScreenActivity}: app died, no saved state
09-05 04:05:56.227: I/ActivityManager(246): Start proc edu.ucla.pam for broadcast edu.ucla.pam/.receiver.ConnectivityReceiver: pid=7325 uid=10008 gids={3003, 3002, 3001, 1015, 1028}
09-05 04:05:56.398: E/AndroidRuntime(7325): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver edu.ucla.pam.receiver.ConnectivityReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.ucla.pam.receiver.ConnectivityReceiver
09-05 04:05:56.398: E/AndroidRuntime(7325): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.ucla.pam.receiver.ConnectivityReceiver
09-05 04:05:56.398: W/ActivityManager(246): Process edu.ucla.pam has crashed too many times: killing!
09-05 04:05:56.398: I/ActivityManager(246): Killing proc 7325:edu.ucla.pam/u0a8: crash
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace and the contents of your updateUI method.

Comment: I do not think the problem is in the updateUI method because it crashes on my test Toast as well. Nevertheless -  I will post the code and the stacktrace.

Comment: @AviC : where is `ConnectivityReceiver.class` ?Make sure you have register  it in manifest correctly or added in right package

Comment: I thought that if you programatically added the broadcastreceiver like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805269/programmatically-register-a-broadcast-receiver you did not have to add it in the manifest. 

It could be the issue - could you please help me out with the code change I will have to do to make sure this works as intended?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the issue was some legacy code. There was an additional ConnectivityReceiver registered in the Manifest that was never instantiated that was caused the application to crash.

I will post the legacy code shortly.

Thanks for all your help.