# use registerReceiver for non activity and non service class

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to `registerReceiver` for BluetoothDevice events like `ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED` , `ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED`.

But the class in which I am using `registerReceiver` does not extend `Activity` class nor `Service` class - so I am passing `Context` to that class and registering receiver as follows

```
context.registerReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver, 
          new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED));

context.registerReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver, 
              new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED));

context.registerReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver, 
          new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED));
```

and handling events as follows

```
private final BroadcastReceiver ActionFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }
};
```

but when the device is connected or disconnected I am not able to trace is I mean the `ActionFoundReceiver` is not able to get called

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried to solve it by using , but i really don't know how safe is this and it is a good practice in this case or not.

if anyone has a better ans feel free to post

```
context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver, 
                  new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED));
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a sketch of a `BroadcastReceiver` that works for me.

You have some class `MyBroadcastReceiver` that does all the work.

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

`MyBroadcastReceiver` is hosted in your `MyClass` (that is not an activity or service)

```
public class MyClass {

    private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = null;

    public MyClass(Context context) {
        myReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
        context.registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED));
        context.registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED));
        context.registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED));
    }

    public void unregisterReceiver(Context context) {
        context.unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    }
}
```

`MyClass` lifetime is controlled by `MyActivity` (or `MyService`) .

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private MyClass myClass = null;

    @Override
    public void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onResume(savedInstanceState);
        // ...
        myClass = new MyClass(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (myClass != null) {
            myClass.unregisterReceiver(this);
            myClass = null;
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

This can also be `onCreate`/`onDestroy` or within a service.

Comment: Shouldn't it be context.unregisterReceiver(myReceiver); ?

Comment: @Flot2011 you are right. I fixed it in my answer

Answer (score 1):

I have some similar problem, i have a receiver for sms sent, i register it but never called.
I tried to do so, and was never called

```
actionfounder= new ActionFounderReceiver();
    context.registerReceiver(actionfounder , new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED));
```

Well, what was my surprises, that it called when i register it this way:

```
context.registerReceiver(new ActionFoundReceiver() , new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED));
```

And the inner class:

```
class ActionFoundReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver() {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     String action = intent.getAction();
     if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
        // do some stuff
     }
   }
}
```

Just when i get a fresh new instance, it's works.

Hope this helps.