# Trouble in stopping broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I am doing an app which will speak the caller name.It is having a main Activity and two broadcast receivers for monitoring incoming calls and SMS. from that receivers it starts an service for speak out the caller name.

The Problem I am facing with this is

```
  I want to start ans stop this broadcast receivers from the UI.i mean with the help of two buttons.
```

Is it possible,If yes how can I do it?

Comment: This answer might be more inline with what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4806091/445348

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  When you want to start it, call registerReceiver.  When you want it off, call unregisterReceiver.

Comment: can u suggest a perfect code i am not able to find an effective one

Answer (score 0):

Register Receiver on Button Click:

```
YourReceiver mReceiver ;
btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                                  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(your action filter);
                     mReceiver = new YourReceiver();
                                 registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }
});
```

Unregistered receiver :

```
 btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
try
        {

            unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException ex)
        {
            //your message.
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I had tried this code but still it invoking the broadcast receiver