# Android closing media service on incoming call

Tags: android, service, media

I'm really new on android and java. I'm making an app and it has a media service and I want the media to be stopped or paused on incoming calls.
This is my media service code

public class ServiceMusic extends Service {

```
MediaPlayer music;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    music.stop();
    music.release();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    if (music !=null)
    music.stop();

    music = MediaPlayer.create(ServiceMusic.this, R.raw.music);
    music.start();
    music.setLooping(true);
}
```

}

I will really appreciate if you can help me with this , and if you can give me a complete instruction that will be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to create receiver for incoming call like below:

```
public class call_reciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String number = "";
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();


        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            // Phone is ringing
            number = bundle.getString("incoming_number");


        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            // Call received

        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            // Call Dropped or rejected


        }


    }
```

in manifest put this:

```
<receiver android:name=".call_reciver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>
```

make your media player variable static & globale, in reciver call another service to check your media player is running or not. if it is running then stop it. you can use also use same service.

you have to start services from receiver:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Service_temp.class);
        context.startService(myIntent);
```

in service use this:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

---

**check edited ans:**

In below example I have done all things. there is one button it ll play song in service. at that time you receive in coming call then it will stop your service(stop playing song) and when you reject or drop call then it again start playing song

main Activity class :

```
package com.example.androidmediaplay;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void clickBtn(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
            UtilClass.playing = true;
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    BackgroundSoundService.class);
            startService(i);
        }
    }

}
```

BackgroundSoundService class:

```
package com.example.androidmediaplay;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = null;
    MediaPlayer player;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(
                this,
                Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/Songs/test.mp3")));
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(100, 100);

    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("onStartCommand", "onStartCommand");
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            player.pause();
            UtilClass.pause = true;

            Log.e("onStartCommand pause", "onStartCommand pause");
        } else {
            UtilClass.pause = false;
            player.start();
        }

        return 1;
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TO DO
    }

    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TO DO Auto-generated method
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {

    }

    public void onPause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        UtilClass.playing = false;
        player.stop();
        player.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {

    }

}
```

call receiver class:

```
package com.example.androidmediaplay;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class call_reciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String number = "";
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            // Phone is ringing
            number = bundle.getString("incoming_number");
            Log.e("incoming_number", "incoming_number");
            _stopServices(context);

        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            // Call received

        } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
            // Call Dropped or rejected
            _stopServices(context);
        }

    }

    private void _stopServices(Context con) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (UtilClass.playing == true) {
            Log.e("start services", "start services");
            Intent i = new Intent(con, BackgroundSoundService.class);
            con.startService(i);
        } else {
            Log.e("start not services", "start not services");
        }
    }

}
```

extra class for static member:

```
package com.example.androidmediaplay;

public class UtilClass {

    public static Boolean playing = false;
    public static boolean pause = false;
}
```

in last manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidmediaplay"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidmediaplay.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".BackgroundSoundService"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </service>

        <receiver android:name=".call_reciver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

All code is working at my end. please check it and tell me.

Comment: thank you for your help, But I didn't know how to make the music variable as global. I'm really new in java and android. I will appreciate if you can help me more with the code coz I'm kind of confusing about the way you told me. thank you very much :)

Comment: You are Awesome , Thank you very much , thumbs up and best answer. Best Regards

Comment: Hi again, Sorry for disturbing you, but I think there is something we need to add to the service because when I exit the application the receiver still working and i get the music playing after ending any call and the app is totally closed. thanks again

Comment: ok then you have to check if you app is running then & then you receiver will work otherwise not. then you have to register receiver in Activity not in manifest. and when your activity destroy then unregister your receiver. check this links:http://stackoverflow.com/a/4805733/1168654 and http://www.sohailaziz.com/2012/05/broadcast-receiver-two-ways-to.html hope you understand. if you have query then write below..