# How to disable receiver registered through manifest?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

There appears to be an issue where a user present broadcast receiver is sometimes not properly triggered when registered through the manifest for some devices running my app. Sometimes it is, sometimes its not. My idea is to have a fallback toggle that runs a persistent service that starts that broadcast instead.

The issue is that I don't want the same receiver being registered twice, so I want do unregister the manifest one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805269/programmatically-register-a-broadcast-receiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot "unregister" it, but you can disable it, using `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`.