# Local broadcast in android?

Tags: java, android, android-broadcast

I have two activity **activityA** and **activityB**.

**activityA** is starting a background process and mean while it will also start **activityB**

**background process** started by **activityA** will finish after sometime. Is it possible to notify **activityB** when process is finish by **activityA** if **activiyB** in foreground and **activotyA** is background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is definitely possible and LocalbroadcastMaanager is a good choice here is how you do it.

In the long running process, write this at the end of the process

```
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(
                new Intent("backgroundProcessCallBack"));
```

And in your activity you should have this (inside oncreate):

```
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
    .registerReceiver(mTaskListener, new IntentFilter("backgroundProcessCallBack"));
```

where mTaskListener is a class level variable (BroadcastReceiver):

```
private BroadcastReceiver mTaskListener = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context cxt, Intent intent) {
        // Do you stuff here. You got the callBack in your activity
    }
};
```

then unregister this receiver in activity's onDestroy() method.

Comment: do not forget to unregister inside onDestroy() or onPause(), your pick.

Comment: Is it possible without LocalBroadcastManager ? is it slowing the process.

Comment: I'm curious: How is it slowing the process down? +1 for LocalBroadcastManager.

Comment: It doesn't slow the process... can you please explain in detail.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two activities running at the same time.
If your background process runs in a `Service`, you can subsribe to broadcasts in `Activity` A and in `Activity` B.
When the work in `Service` is finished, it sends broadcast - and whatever `Activity` (A or B) is in foreground - it will receive a `Broadcast`.

Sample code here: [Programmatically register a broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805269/programmatically-register-a-broadcast-receiver)

Comment: I want to send notification from acitvity A to B while activity A in background and B in foreground.

Comment: @Lavekush I am not sure if your Thread will be alive when you launch Activity B. I suggest you better use `IntentService` or `Service` - it's not hard to implement.

Comment: @Lavekush if you launch Activity B, your Activity A is stopped and destroyed.

Comment: not necessary Activity A will destroy its depend on android runtime system.