# Disabling BroadcastReceiver class from another actvity?

Tags: android, android-activity, permissions, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have 2 activities : 1. BroadCastReceiver 2. Settings. I am writing a condition in Settings activity that upon being satisfied, should disable the BroadCastReceiver class or the BroadCastReceiver class should not run until I reverse the condition in Settings Activity. However the problem is that BroadCastReceiver class is called through the Manifest file where I have given it a persmission :

```
android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"
```

Now, I am not able to figure out how to disable the BroadCastReceiver class via Setting activity ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't configure the BroadcastReceiver in the Manifest file. Instead register and unregister it programmatically.

Check out [this discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805269/programmatically-register-a-broadcast-receiver)