# Values not passed between Intent Service and Class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, handler

**Explanation:**
I made this intent service in a new class (connectionchecker.java) which is used to check for internet connection.
Now in my main class (First.java), the values are not recieved because the if() is never executed.
My app **doesn't crash**, the problem is the TextView is stuck on "CONNECTION:" instead of saying "CONNECTION:You are not connected to the internet." or ""CONNECTION:You are not connected to the internet.".

**Code:**
First.java

```js
package com.lofty.lofti;

import com.lofty.lofti.util.SystemUiHider;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 *
 * @see SystemUiHider
 */
public class First extends Activity {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * If set, will toggle the system UI visibility upon interaction. Otherwise,
     * will show the system UI visibility upon interaction.
     */
    private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;

    /**
     * The flags to pass to {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance}.
     */
    private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

    /**
     * The instance of the {@link SystemUiHider} for this activity.
     */
    private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().hide(); // HIDE ACTION BAR.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);




        EditText enter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbox);
        enter.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    EditText searchbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbox);
                    String search = searchbox.getText().toString();
                    Intent open = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
                    open.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, search);
                    startActivity(open);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class Connection extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Integer connectionn = intent.getIntExtra("connection",0);
            TextView connectiontext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connectiontext);

            if(connectionn==1)
            {
                    connectiontext.setText("CONNECTION:You are not connected to the internet.");
            }
            if(connectionn==0)
            {
                    connectiontext.setText("CONNECTION:You are not connected to the internet.");

            }
        }
    }

    public void exit(View view)
     {
         finish();
         System.exit(0);
     }

    public void usernameclick (View view)
    {
        EditText searchbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbox);
        String search = searchbox.getText().toString();
        Intent open = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        open.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, search);
        startActivity(open);

    }


}
```

connectionchecker.java

```js
package com.lofty.lofti;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class connectionchecker extends IntentService
{
    public static final int connection =0;

    public connectionchecker() {
        super("connectionchecker");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED|| connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET).getState()== NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)

        {

            Intent data = new Intent(this, First.class);
            data.putExtra("connection",1);
            sendBroadcast(data);
        }
        else
        {
            Intent data = new Intent(this, First.class);
            data.putExtra("connection", 0 );
            sendBroadcast(data);
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lofty.lofti" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".First"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".connectionchecker"/>
        <receiver android:name=".First$Connection"/>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Thank you and have a good day.

Logcat:

```js
10-23 16:01:25.765    2175-2175/com.lofty.lofti E/Zygote﹕ MountEmulatedStorage()
10-23 16:01:25.765    2175-2175/com.lofty.lofti E/Zygote﹕ v2
10-23 16:01:25.775    2175-2175/com.lofty.lofti I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_GT-I9505_5.0.1 ver=27
10-23 16:01:25.775    2175-2175/com.lofty.lofti I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_GT-I9505_5.0.1-1_0032
10-23 16:01:25.775    2175-2175/com.lofty.lofti E/SELinux﹕ [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
10-23 16:01:25.775    2175-2175/com.lofty.lofti I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
10-23 16:01:25.955    2175-2175/com.lofty.lofti D/ResourcesManager﹕ creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/com.lofty.lofti-2/base.apk
10-23 16:01:26.185    2175-2175/com.lofty.lofti D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-23 16:01:26.195    2175-2175/com.lofty.lofti E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.lofty.lofti, PID: 2175
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lofty.lofti/com.lofty.lofti.First}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:309)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:278)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:252)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.lofty.lofti.First.onCreate(First.java:68)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
10-23 16:06:26.538    2175-2175/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2175 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just update your code, by following the tuto from Lars http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

1. You have to register the broadcast receiver before it can receive anything.
   Have a look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4806091/2733216

   ```
   IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Connection.ACTION_RESP);
   registerReceiver(mConnection, filter);
   ```
2. Your service wasn't started (at least in the code you provided)

   in your Activity 'onCreate'

   ```
   // Start your Service
   Intent msgIntent = new Intent(this, ConnectionChecker.class);
   startService(msgIntent);
   ```
3. You didn't instantiate your BroadCastReceiver

   ```
   // Instanciate your BCR
   mConnection = new Connection();
   ```
4. Define a message :

   ```
   public static final String ACTION_RESP = "intent.action.MESSAGE_PROCESSED";
   ```
5. Define the message to the Intent

   ```
   data.setAction(MainActivity.Connection.ACTION_RESP);
   ```
6. Use Default Intent Constructor for the one that are sent from the Service

   ```
   Intent data = new Intent();
   ```

Then finally, the whole code :

1. Activity

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ```
   private Connection mConnection;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



       EditText enter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbox);
       enter.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
               if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                   EditText searchbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbox);
                   String search = searchbox.getText().toString();
                   Intent open = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
                   open.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, search);
                   startActivity(open);
                   return true;
               } else {
                   return false;
               }
           }
       });

       // Start your Service
       Intent msgIntent = new Intent(this, ConnectionChecker.class);
       startService(msgIntent);

       // Instanciate BCR
       mConnection = new Connection();
       // Register BCR
       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Connection.ACTION_RESP);
       registerReceiver(mConnection, filter);

   }

   public class Connection extends BroadcastReceiver {
       public static final String ACTION_RESP = "intent.action.MESSAGE_PROCESSED";

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           Integer connectionn = intent.getIntExtra("connection", 0);
           TextView connectiontext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connectiontext);

           if (connectionn == 1)
               connectiontext.setText("CONNECTION:You are not connected to the internet.");
           else
               connectiontext.setText("CONNECTION:You are not connected to the internet.");

       }
   }

   public void exit(View view) {
       finish();
       System.exit(0);
   }

   public void usernameclick(View view) {
       EditText searchbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbox);
       String search = searchbox.getText().toString();
       Intent open = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
       open.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, search);
       startActivity(open);

   }
   ```

   }
2. Service

   public class ConnectionChecker extends IntentService
   {
       public static final int connection =0;

   ```
   public ConnectionChecker() {
       super("connectionchecker");

   }

   @Override
   protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
       ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
       if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED|| connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET).getState()== NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)

       {

           Intent data = new Intent();
           data.setAction(MainActivity.Connection.ACTION_RESP);
           data.putExtra("connection", 1);
           sendBroadcast(data);


       }
       else
       {
           Intent data = new Intent();
           data.setAction(MainActivity.Connection.ACTION_RESP);
           data.putExtra("connection", 0 );
           sendBroadcast(data);
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: I read that page many times but it's not clear enough for me :/ if you have the code answer for my issue please post it and I will try my best to understand

Comment: I inspected and put the code you gave me in android studio, no errors while compuling but the apps now crashes **upon start-up**. 
Here's the logcat: http://pastebin.com/39RRmYsd
First.java : http://pastebin.com/xtgJMKQK
connectionchecker.java : http://pastebin.com/8RMrTrBK

I've put the codes there since you can't add them here, too many chars

Comment: Ok, ill add it to my first post.

Comment: This is just a theme issue, just extends from Activity and not from AppCompActivity

Comment: add this `@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    unregisterReceiver(mConnection);
    super.onStop();
}`in your activity

Comment: but there is another issue about the network info that is not about what we are chatting :     `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.NetworkInfo$State android.net.NetworkInfo.getState()' on a null object reference
            at com.lofty.lofti.connectionchecker.onHandleIntent(connectionchecker.java:21)`

Comment: The issues were with the deprecated getNetworkInfo , I switched it up to getActiveNetworkInfo and it's working now ! Messages are working properly ! Now if I want to make the service (connectionchecker) happen lets say every 5 seconds after onCreate, how should I set up the loop in your opinion? and then break the loop once the application is paused/destroyed. Thanks a lot bro !

Answer (score 0):

> the values are not received because the if() is never executed

Pass an action for the `Intent`, instead of using like this:

```
Intent data = new Intent(this, First.class);
```

But, you should:

```
Intent data = new Intent("ACTION_NAME");
```

And make sure that you registered that action to manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".First$Connection">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="ACTION_NAME" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

> the problem is the TextView is stuck

Make an instance variable for `connectiontext`:

```
public class First extends Activity {

    ...
    private TextView connectiontext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        getActionBar().hide(); // HIDE ACTION BAR.
        connectiontext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connectiontext);
        ...
    }
...
}
```

Comment: which action should I use? ACTION_RESP ?

Comment: @JamesJackson, the action's name is up to you. You don't need to use `ACTION_RESP`. But remember that you have to give the same name to manifest as I described above.

Comment: Okay so I did what you told me, the TextView is still "Connection:" :/ 




First.java http://pastebin.com/xjXTsVm4
connectionchecker.java: http://pastebin.com/S87CFxwG
AndroidManifest.xml: http://pastebin.com/mUUf8FRa



Do you want the logcat too?

Comment: @JamesJackson, why don't you use `boolean connected = intent.getBooleanExtra("connection", false);` and send it through `data.putExtra("connection", true);`? Also, use `Intent data = new Intent("ACTION_NAME");`

Comment: alright I did everything you said and the textview is still not changing, I added an Intent in onCreate to start the service which is now making the app crash.

Comment: @JamesJackson, your error is refers to http://stackoverflow.com/q/21814825/3922207. Please read.

Comment: The issues were with the deprecated getNetworkInfo , I switched it up to getActiveNetworkInfo and it's working now ! Messages are working properly ! Now if I want to make the service (connectionchecker) happen lets say every 5 seconds after onCreate, how should I set up the loop in your opinion? and then break the loop once the application is paused/destroyed. Thanks a lot bro !