# alarm Reminder is not working in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am working in an app which uses Fragment in which there is a  reminder with time picker but my ReminderPage class do not go to BroadcastReceiver class,I cannot find out why this is happening.

Here is my code for `RemiderPage.java`.

```
public class ReminderPage extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
View view;
Button Setalarm;
TimePicker timePicker;
final static int RQS_1=1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reminder, container, false);
    timePicker=(TimePicker)view.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    Setalarm=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button8);
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    timePicker.setCurrentHour(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    Setalarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(timePicker.getCurrentHour(), timePicker.getCurrentMinute(), 00);

            setAlarm(cal);
        }


        private void setAlarm(Calendar targetcal) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Alarm is set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext().getApplicationContext(),AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext().getApplicationContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmmanager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmmanager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetcal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

}

And here is my code for `AlarmReceiver.java`.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Toast.makeText(context,"Alarm received",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: I have also tried getActivity() instead of getContext() but nothing happened.Can anybody help?????

Comment: Please make sure that it is working in activity context.

Comment: I can't understand what actually you want to say??

Comment: You said it is not working inside the fragment. So please check whether it is working in activity.

Comment: No it is also not working in activity..

Comment: Have you registerd the BroadcastReceiver  in manifest ?

Comment: No.  how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please register your receiver inside application node of manifest.xml file.

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true">   
</receiver>
```

Please check below link, for further information.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html

You can register programmatically also. please check the below ink.

[Programmatically register a broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805269/programmatically-register-a-broadcast-receiver)

Comment: Thanks! I have register receiver in my manifest and it worked.

Comment: I have one more issue that my code doesn't recognize whether it's AM Or PM. Can you help me.

Comment: You need to identify the AM/PM in the receiver rt?

Comment: Use this code -- if(calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0) am_pm = "AM"; else am_pm = "PM"