# How to initialized ListView of a layout?

Tags: android, listview

I want to update ListView of layout `activity_call_history.xml` contain `ListView Id/call_history_listview` into a class `CallRecordService.java` in the Android.

So, I don't know how to initialized `ListView` to apply to this `ListView`.

Current, I initialized with code:

`listView = new ListView(context);`

I search on the Internet, all people usually using like code:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_call_history, container, false);
listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.call_history_listview);
```

But in my class can't create rootView like this code.

How to initialized listView contain `R.id.call_history_listview` in `layout activity_call_history`?

This is class `CallRecordService.java`:
http://pastebin.com/6xr72uJ4

Thank you.

Comment: listView = new ListView(context);

how did you get context here..?

Comment: Please paste your Upload.java

Comment: @ShadabAnsari I updated this file. pastebin.com/6xr72uJ4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the code provided by you, you are creating to instantiate `ListView` in your `Service` class.

```
public class CallRecordService extends Service {
```

Any class extending `Service` class cannot have UI or cannot have access to UI elements. Wherever you've inflated your `ListView` either in a activity or a fragment, you have to set the adapter in that file. The way to do that is you can send the broadcast from your service after your job is done.  The activity/fragment containing your `ListView` will listen to this broadcast and update the ListView appropriately.

Comment: Thank you very much @Shadab Ansari, can you write example code or relate link? I understand your answer but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: There are several samples available on web. You need to search for "How to communicate between service and activity".  You can try these two links also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805269/programmatically-register-a-broadcast-receiver     and https://androidexperinz.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/communication-between-service-and-activity-part-1/

Comment: Thank you with your answer.