# Disable push notifcations for current app android java

Tags: java, android, push-notification

its possible to disable push notifications for current app ?
i was using example from google GCM notifications. And in app , i want when i logout - disable push notifications . It's possible to do from code or its need disable only on server where push notifications send to me

Regard, Peter.

**[upd]**
Thank you Oleg and also i found a way do this in MessageReceiver

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

        String message = data.getString("message");
        if(notificationsDisabled) {
           // do what u want when notifications variable disabled (without server etc)
        }else{
            // if enabled , show notifications message in status bar or something else
        }
     }
```

its good way when need update something from server but without push notifications

Comment: yes just unregister your device from GCM Server or delete the Token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually register your `GcmBroadcastReceiver` at starup and unregister on exit

[Programmatically register a broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805269/programmatically-register-a-broadcast-receiver)