# How to use or implement Broadcast Receiver in Xamarin.Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

How to use Broadcast Reciever in Xamarin.Form reference to this forum http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7070/how-to-prevent-sms-going-to-inbox

the class

```
  public class SmsReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
  {

    public static readonly string IntentAction = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        InvokeAbortBroadcast();
        try
        {
            if (intent.Action != IntentAction) return;

            var bundle = intent.Extras;

            if (bundle == null) return;

            var pdus = bundle.Get("pdus");
            var castedPdus = JNIEnv.GetArray<Java.Lang.Object>(pdus.Handle);

            var msgs = new SmsMessage[castedPdus.Length];

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            String sender = null;
            for (var i = 0; i < msgs.Length; i++)
            {
                var bytes = new byte[JNIEnv.GetArrayLength(castedPdus[i].Handle)];
                JNIEnv.CopyArray(castedPdus[i].Handle, bytes);

                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.CreateFromPdu(bytes);
                if (sender == null) sender = msgs[i].OriginatingAddress;
                sb.Append(string.Format("SMS From: {0}{1}Body: {2}{1}", msgs[i].OriginatingAddress,
                                        System.Environment.NewLine, msgs[i].MessageBody));
            }


            if (sender != null && sender.EndsWith("09068100820"))
            {

                // Process our sms...
                //        SMS.updateMessageBox("\nFrom: " + msg.getOriginatingAddress() + "\n" +
                //"Message: " + msg.getMessageBody() + "\n");
                /*((SMS) context).delete();*/
                Toast.MakeText(context, "IsOrderedBroadcast :" + IsOrderedBroadcast.ToString() + "\n" + sb.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            else
            {
                ClearAbortBroadcast();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

How to implement this class in Xamarin.Form and get the incoming SMS, Thanks in advance and Good Day :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Android 4.4`, You can't do any kind of operation on SMS except just reading it if your app isn't the default SMS app.

If your app is default sms app and you want to block sender or whatever then put your `SmsReceiver` in `Android Project` and register it in `Application` class.

I don't think you need to do anything in `Forms Project`.

Comment: my target is API 23 or Android 6.0

Comment: Then you can't do it if you won't make your app default SMS app.

Comment: are you referring to this http://www.trishtech.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/default-sms-app-android-0.jpg

Comment: how do i register it in Application class?

Comment: You should register it where you initialize `Xamarin.Forms`, `FormsApplicationActivity`.

And this is how you register a reciever
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4805733/3423468