# broadcastreceiver not fired with twilio

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, twilio, android-pendingintent

Implementing twilio for calls , I try to use broadcast receiver instead of activity for the twilio logic. My broadcast receiver is supposed to catch an intent through `onReceive()`, but actually it doesn't. 
The call is heared ! but cannot catch the event and proceed within my activity

My broadcastreceiver (`TwilioBroadCastReceiver`) contains :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
        /*
         * Determine if the receiving Intent has an extra for the incoming connection. If so,
         * remove it from the Intent to prevent handling it again next time the Activity is resumed
         */
        Device device = intent.getParcelableExtra(Device.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        Connection incomingConnection = intent.getParcelableExtra(Device.EXTRA_CONNECTION);

        if (incomingConnection == null && device == null) {
            return;
        }
        intent.removeExtra(Device.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        intent.removeExtra(Device.EXTRA_CONNECTION);

        pendingConnection = incomingConnection;
        pendingConnection.setConnectionListener(this);
        showIncomingDialog();
    }
}
```

and

```
private void createDevice(String capabilityToken) {
    try {
        if (clientDevice == null) {
            clientDevice = Twilio.createDevice(capabilityToken, this);
            Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, TwilioBroadcastReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mActivity, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            clientDevice.setIncomingIntent(pendingIntent);
        } else {
            clientDevice.updateCapabilityToken(capabilityToken);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "An error has occured updating or creating a Device: \n" + e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Device error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

in my activity :

```
mReceiver = new TwilioBroadcastReceiver(this, clientProfile);
```

someone have an idea ?   tks

Manifest , hummm.... seems something missing there  ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="client.twilio.com.quickstart">

<!-- needed for monitoring network availability -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<!-- needed for processing on the network -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<!-- needed to enable/disable the speakerphone -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>

<!-- needed to receive audio from microphone during a call -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".ClientActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.twilio.client.TwilioClientService" android:exported="false" android:stopWithTask="true"/>
</application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you registered your broadcast in your activity? If not, check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805269/programmatically-register-a-broadcast-receiver

Comment: I thought about this too . but I use Twilio Sdk which I suppose should do it for me with: PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: .... besides this I don't have any filter specification to register it .

Comment: post your manifest please

Comment: I added the manifest. i am gonna see if a add the broadcast in it i can get more success

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the `BroadcastReceiver` in your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".TwilioBroadcastReceiver"/>
```

otherwise, the Twilio application cannot deliver the `PendingIntent` to it.
You do not need any `<intent-filter>` for the `<receiver>` because you are providing an explicit `Intent` to trigger it.