# Priority of kill commands in Android

Tags: android, android-service, kill-process

I recently asked a question about [background services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44820439/background-services-causing-crash) where I was not supplying `Intent` data correctly to the onStartComment after a `START_STICKY` restart. The restart was due to Android killing my services when the system was overloaded. Seems Android will "can (and will) stop your Service whenever it wants to" or to put another way "Anything in Android can be killed at any point, for instance if the system has few resources"

This got me thinking: Is there any order to (and therefore can we predict, or control) what Android will kill first, e.g. services then apps, or apps open but unused for some time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer to the following articles on the priority of processes in Android. it will answer your question.

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/processes/process-lifecycle.html
- https://medium.com/google-developers/who-lives-and-who-dies-process-priorities-on-android-cb151f39044f

Comment: Thanks - that helped a lot.