# Android Nougat how use registerReceiver()?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have class to receive network change, it work in apk <= 23.
I read in nugat i must use context.registerReceiver() but i don't know how/where use it, please help me.

```
public class syncNetworkStateChecker extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (checkNetworkConnection(context)) { something todo }
}

public boolean checkNetworkConnection(Context context)
{
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return  (networkInfo!= null && networkInfo.isConnected());
}
```

In MainActivity i add code:

```
    ComponentName reciver = new ComponentName(getBaseContext(), syncNetworkStateChecker.class);
    PackageManager pm = getBaseContext().getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(reciver, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);


    final String SOME_ACTION = "CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE";
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(SOME_ACTION);

    brodcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            syncNetworkStateChecker start = new syncNetworkStateChecker();
            Intent intent_sync = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BackgroundLocation.class);
            start.onReceive(getBaseContext(), intent_sync);

        }
    };
    registerReceiver(brodcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    Intent i2 = new Intent(SOME_ACTION);
    sendBroadcast(i2);
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically register a broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805269/programmatically-register-a-broadcast-receiver)

Comment: but i don't have onCreate method in this class and i don't know how solve this..

Comment: Do you at least have an Activity ?? If yes then just follow the link above .

Comment: Yes, I have but i understand how i use this, I wrote (in MainActivity) see above please i update code.

Comment: Well that will work. You should use onResume() and onPause() to Register and Unregister BR. I do not think there is any changes regarding register a BR from android N its the same as previous..

Comment: But i wont use network state chacker in background, what i must do registerReceiver work always ?

Comment: If you only want when your app is open . Then go for runtime register/ unregister . Although after Android N or maybe from N there are some limitations on static(Registered in manifest) broadcast receivers .in your case you should do it as you written above .i.e At runtime .

Comment: I edit my post, please see. But it still work only when i go to MainActivity, what i must do then works always in backgorund?

Comment: You must be kidding me ..That's the expected behavior . For What you want network in background ? Do you have any Background service or Job scheduler

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not specify it. I have service with GPS position and I use class syncNetworkStateChecker to detect when is internet connection and sent data from local sqlLite to remote mysql server.